# Symbolic equation solver in python

Tags: python, latex, equation, solver

I want a python function, that solves given system of equations to given parameters. For example:

```
 >>>>foo("""\begin{cases}
 & c^2=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 \cdot \mu_0}\\ 
 & k_E=\frac{1}{4 \cdot \pi \epsilon_0} \\ 
 & \epsilon_0=1+\chi_0
\end{cases}""","\chi_0",("c","\mu_0"))
#outputs:
\frac{c^2 \cdot \mu_0-1}{c^2 \cdot \mu_0}

>>>>foo("""\begin{cases}
 & c^2=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 \cdot \mu_0}\\ 
 & k_E=\frac{1}{4 \cdot \pi \epsilon_0} \\ 
 & \epsilon_0=1+\chi_0
\end{cases}""","\chi_0",("k_E","\pi"))
#outputs:
\frac{1-k_E \cdot 4 \cdot \pi}{k_E \cdot 4 \cdot \pi}

>>>>foo("A+B+C=D","A",("B","C","D"))
#outputs:
D-B-C
```

First argument of the example function foo is equation. Second argument is variable to solve for. Third argument is tuple of arguments that can be used in solution. In the example the equation system is written in LaTeX, but it is not important, what language the solver uses.
Should I use an importable modul?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). It's widely used for symbolic processing by many projects so it's very likely that it has you covered

In the [solvers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html) section try `linsolve([x + y + z - 1, x + y + 2*z - 3 ], (x, y, z))` , it will solve for x. If you want to solve for y replace `(x,y,z)` with `(y,x,z)` and so on

Comment: I Have looked from sympy documentation, but I did not find any suitable function for that.